# Widgetkit Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-@-cover]

Tags: jquery, yoothemes, joomla-widgetkit

With yootheme VENICE and Widgetkit 2.0, I get the following error when inserting a Gallery widget in my articles in joomla.

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-@-cover]
```

Does anybody know what is this and how to fix it?

This is the calls stack:

```
Sizzle</Sizzle.error@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:1458:8
Sizzle</Sizzle.tokenize@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2075:4
Sizzle</Sizzle.select@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2479:20
Sizzle@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:855:9
.find@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2695:4
jQuery.fn.init@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2808:12
e.fn.init@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js:2:2848
jQuery@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:76:10
.boot/<@http://gutenberginstitute.com/templates/yoo_venice/warp/vendor/uikit/js/components/cover.js:1:325
@http://gutenberginstitute.com/templates/yoo_venice/warp/vendor/uikit/js/uikit.js:1:8286
@http://gutenberginstitute.com/templates/yoo_venice/warp/vendor/uikit/js/uikit.js:1:8251
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:4434:15
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:4121:6
jQuery.event.trigger@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:4350:5
e.event.trigger@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js:2:6730
.trigger/<@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:4901:4
.each@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:374:14
jQuery.prototype.each@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:139:10
.trigger@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:4900:1
e.trigger@http://gutenberginstitute.com/templates/yoo_venice/warp/vendor/uikit/js/uikit.js:1:7864
@http://gutenberginstitute.com/templates/yoo_venice/warp/vendor/uikit/js/uikit.js:1:9112
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3099:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3211:7
.ready@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3417:1
completed@http://gutenberginstitute.com/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:3433:2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is already fixed. It was related to different uikit.js version (2.18) and templates (2.20) and yoo_theme out of date. Update your yoo_theme version and all the rest will be fixed automatically!